# Accessing external properties file while running jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file with java classes where I am accessing properties file for DB details. Now we have removed all properties file from **src/resources** folder and we want to access this properties file from one common folder(jar and properties file will be in different location but in same machine).

**I tried below but got error**

java -DApp.config.file=/demo/demo1/test.properties -DlogEnv=DEV -jar test.jar argumet1 argument2

**Error**:
Could not find or load main class -DApp.config.file=.demo.demo1.test.properties

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the command `java -DApp.config.file=/demo/demo1/test.properties -DlogEnv=DEV -jar test.jar argumet1 argument2` is not the exact command that you tried issuing.